# Conditional skipping of unit tests

Tags: junit, conditional-statements, suppress

I'm currently working on a class, dealing with network issues. Using JUnit 3.8.1 and having a hardware device, that's not always around to test against, I'd like to conditionally suppress individual tests. Is there a way to achive this with a simple annotation like @if(!gatewayAvailable) -> test's suppressed?

Thanx for any pointers, marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in JUnit 3.8.1. You have to use JUnit4 and its [Assume class](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assume.html).

Comment: I've added some more packages and made the distinction in the suite builder. not as nice, but does it's job.